# available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement Kafka producer which sends and receives Java Serialized Objects. I tried this:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }
}
```

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> kafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
    transaction.setStatus(PaymentTransactionStatus.IN_PROGRESS.getText());

    Transaction insertedTransaction = transactionService.save(transaction);

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = kafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactory.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String>
    kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

// Receive Object

```
    private static String topic = "tp-sale";

    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
    public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(tf.getId());

        SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
        resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

        return resObj;
    }
```

When I deploy the Producer I get error during deployment:

`Application failed to start due to an exception org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate<java.lang.String, org.engine.plugin              .transactions.factory.SaleRequestFactory>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.fac              tory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}`

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

***EDIT:***
I managed to implement these improvements:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

}

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

// Receive Object

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
        
        private int id;
    }

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data) {
        // convert data to byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
        private String unique_id;
    }

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleResponseFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleResponseFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // convert data to SaleResponseFactory
        SaleResponseFactory saleResponseFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleResponseFactory = (SaleResponseFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleResponseFactory;
    }
}
```

When I send some message I get error:

```
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - Listener method returned result [org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab] - generating response message for it
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - No replyTopic to handle the reply: org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab
```

Do you know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the update part - I believe the debug messages are misleading as you are not opting in to forward results to another topic. More details [`here`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#annotation-send-to). Everything appears to be working as expected. I think there needs to be a way to skip the entire forwarding including logging when the listener return type is not `Message` or `@SendTo` annotation is used which is required for forwarding. I've dropped a [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55408048/forwarding-spring-kafkalistener-result-with-sendto/55418608#comment114563720_55418608) for spring kafka committer to see what he thinks.

Comment: Ok, I got your idea. I have to add `@SendTo` for the consumer to return the response object. But I have 2 questions: 1. This looks like a Async communication. I need Sync communication. 2. Can you show me how I need to modify the Producer in order to get the returned Object?.

Comment: For the first part - I don't follow you - What is your use case ? kafka producer is inherently async -  For the second part - What do you need the return object for ?

Comment: Please ignore the the first part before EDIT. Into `perform()` I want to get from the producer `SaleResponsetFactory` object.

Comment: Have you tried injecting kafka template/producer with appropriate serializer ? As you are using java serialization make sure both the request/response are same object type.

Comment: Yes, but in my case I cant to send and receive different object type.

Comment: If you like to keep different type you can  configure  json serializer and deserializer in producer and consumer factories to convert between byte arrays and java pojos

Comment: I want to send directly serialized objects as you can see into the code above.

Comment: Okay. If I follow you, you  would need to add another serializer to serialize SaleResponseFactory into byte arrays  including separate producer/template beans.

Answer (score 2):

The only `KafkaTemplate` bean you have is

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

Try declaring another bean with needed generics:

```
@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

You will also need corresponding `ProducerFactory`:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);

    // Serialization configuration
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}
```

Comment: For `<>` I get `Cannot infer arguments`

Comment: Fixed my answer: you will need the corresponding `ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory>`

Comment: Now I get `org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}`

Comment: Did you remove `KafkaTemplate<String, String>` ? Try declaring _another_ bean, don't remove existing

Comment: hm... looks like i need to have also a second `ProducerFactory`?

Comment: Yes, in order to declare another `KafkaTemplate`

Comment: ok, got it. What is the proper way to configure the consumer?

Comment: Updated my answer with Consumer configuration

Comment: Are you sure that I need to send JsonDeserializer? I want to send Java Objects. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64740384/implement-properly-serialize-and-deserialize-for-kafka-custom-object